# Pivot table in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This is my record in my table

```
GuestName      F1    H1    F2  H2  F3   H3
Ryan Palma     1200  Room  12  SC  14   VAT
Richard Palma  1500  Room  15  SC  17   VAT
Ruth Palma     1600  Room  16  SV  18   VAT
```

I want an output like this

```
GuestName      Room  SC  VAT
Ryan Palma     1200  12  14
Richard Palma  1500  15  17
Ruth Palma     1600  16  18
```

How can i do this using query,

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
select guestname,f1 as Room,f2 as SC,f3 as VAT from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using this query:-

```
Select GuestName, F1 as Room, F2 as SC, F3 as VAT from your_table_name;
```